# In Google Sheets how do I query another sheet for a column matching a particular date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets named 'MAR 2022' and 'Roster'.  I am wanting to query the Roster sheet and display the header and value that matches a date value in another cell in the MAR 2022 sheet.

`QUERY('Roster'!,"select A, B where A = DATE '"&TEXT('MAR 2022'!$A$2,"yyy-MM-dd")&"' ",1)`

In the Roster sheet, I have a Date column and headers for activities "Laundry", "Clean Floors", with the name of person beneath.  Each date has its own row.  In the MAR 2022 I want to basically be a calendar that shows for each day and who is responsible for the activity.

[Roster Sheet]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsfH.png

[MAR 2022 Sheet]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TQun.png

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: any feed-back on the proposals?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, there are likely other ways to solve this but using query I would suggest changing how the source table is laid out since query does not provide for concatenation of 2 columns (Ex. you want to show the duty and person's name combined, Laundry: John)

I was able to accomplish by changing your roster source table as follows:

[image]

The March tab looks like the following:

[image]

The formula for the days of the week is:

```
=text(A2, "ddd")
```

The date functions in A2 is:

```
=transpose(Roster!A2:A)
```

The QUERY() functions in A2 thru E2:

=query(Roster!$F$1:$H, "SELECT G WHERE F = DATE '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' LABEL G ''", 1)

Answer (score 0):

try with row#2 as date formatted dd

```
=query((arrayformula(split(flatten(Roster!$B$1:$D$1&": "&Roster!$B$2:$D&"~"&Roster!$A$2:$A),"~"))),"select Col1 where Col2="&A2&" ")
```

and drag to the right

[image]